# python sort dictionary by descending order of key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to sort this dictionary d based on integer keys.

```
d = { '123': 'aaa',
      '124': 'bbb,
      '125': 'ccc',
    }
```

So final dictionary would look like this.

```
d = { '125': 'ccc',
      '124': 'bbb',
      '123': 'aaa,
    }
```

I know that Dictionaries do not have any inherent order. But is it achievable?

Comment: Look into `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Modify the code in the dupe by passing a `key` to `sorted`.

Comment: @Arjun  why you want to do this?

Comment: What's your purpose by doing that? Just to get the reversely sorted output?

Comment: How is what achievable?  You can not sort the dictionary.  So what do you want to sort?

Comment: @Sanket If you insert elements in sorted order... doesn't that imply that the dictionary is sorted?

Comment: The purpose is I'm getting the data from mail server using python IMAPClient which doesn't support sorting. So I had to go for pythonic way.